# Get Derived DTO From Base Class Request Body DTO

Tags: java, spring, jackson, polymorphism, dto

I try to get derived class fields from methods response body. Request body parameter is type of base class. Request comes with derived class fields but I can't cast it to derived class.

Here is my controller method and DTO classes:

Method:

```
 @PostMapping("/{code}")
    public ResponseEntity<PromotionDto> createPromotion(@PathVariable String code, @RequestBody PromotionDto promotion){
        if(PromotionTypeEnum.ORDER_THRESHOLD_DISCOUNT.equals(promotion.getPromotionType())) {
            promotionService.createPromotion(orderThresholdDiscountPromotionConverter.toEntity((OrderThresholdDiscountPromotionDto)promotion));
        }
        return ResponseEntity.ok(promotion);
    }
```

Base class DTO:

```
import dto.base.BaseDto;
import promotionservice.PromotionTypeEnum;
import lombok.Data;
import lombok.EqualsAndHashCode;
import lombok.ToString;

@Data
@EqualsAndHashCode(callSuper = true)
@ToString(callSuper = true)
public class PromotionDto extends BaseDto {
    private String code;
    private String title;
    private String description;
    private PromotionTypeEnum promotionType;

}
```

Derived class DTO:

```
import lombok.Data;
import lombok.EqualsAndHashCode;
import lombok.ToString;

@Data
@EqualsAndHashCode(callSuper = true)
@ToString(callSuper = true)
public class OrderThresholdDiscountPromotionDto extends PromotionDto {
    private Double thresholdTotal;
    private Double discountPrice;
    private String messageFired;
    private String messageCouldHaveFired;
}
```

Request JSON is:

```
{
    "code":"qwewe",
    "title":"qwewe",
    "description":"qwewe",
    "promotionType":"ORDER_THRESHOLD_DISCOUNT",
    "thresholdTotal":1.3,
    "discountPrice":"12.5",
    "messageFired":"qwewe",
    "messageCouldHaveFired":"qwewe"

}
```

as result, service returns error:

```
{
"type": "https://www.jhipster.tech/problem/problem-with-message",
"title": "Internal Server Error",
"status": 500,
"detail": "promotion.PromotionDto cannot be cast to promotion.OrderThresholdDiscountPromotionDto",
"path": "/api/promotionresults/qwewe",
"message": "error.http.500"
```

}

> My question is: is there any way, library, annotation etc. to get the
>   derived class instance from request ?

Comment: What is the issue? I see that in your ResponseEntity you return the promotion obj passed as input to the method and not the new created obj

Comment: I've edit the question.

Comment: So I guess the error happens on this line `promotionService.createPromotion(orderThresholdDiscountPromotionConverter.toEntity((OrderThresholdDiscountPromotionDto)promotion));` what I see in the request JSON is that `discountPrice` is a String instead of `Double`. May you post the server side logs?

Comment: java.lang.ClassCastException: promotion.PromotionDto cannot be cast to promotion.OrderThresholdDiscountPromotionDto

Comment: Well `OrderThresholdDiscountPromotionDto` is a subclass of `PromotionDto`; what happens in this case? Spring Will translate the JSON in a `PromotionDto` as you specified in input and so the input object will never be the type you are waiting for

Comment: So you say it is impossible to get OrderThresholdDiscountPromotionDto instance from PromotionDto reference ? Maybe there is an annotation for DTOs ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/190014/discussion-between-gariptipici-and-angelo-immediata).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [Jackson inheritance](https://www.baeldung.com/jackson-inheritance) feature. Annotate `PromotionDto` class as below:

```
@JsonTypeInfo(
    use = JsonTypeInfo.Id.NAME,
    include = JsonTypeInfo.As.PROPERTY,
    property = "promotionType")
@JsonSubTypes({
    @Type(value = OrderThresholdDiscountPromotionDto.class, name = "ORDER_THRESHOLD_DISCOUNT"),
})
class PromotionDto {
```

and remove:

```
private PromotionTypeEnum promotionType;
```

property. It will be handled automatically by `Jackson`. In controller you will be able to use `instanceof`.

Answer (score -1):

What are you trying to do is you are trying typecast the Parent into a child which is known as **Downcasting**. This is only valid when you have the Parent as an instance of child. In your case,  **PromotionDto** should be an instance of **OrderThresholdDiscountPromotionDto**.

Please refer below example:

```
public class PromotionDto  {
    private String code;
    private String title;
    private String description;




    public static void main(String[] args) {

      PromotionDto promotionDto = new OrderThresholdDiscountPromotionDto();
      PromotionDto promotionDto_2 = new PromotionDto();

    //Valid downcasting
      OrderThresholdDiscountPromotionDto subClass1 = (OrderThresholdDiscountPromotionDto)promotionDto;

      //Invalid down casting
      OrderThresholdDiscountPromotionDto subClass2 = (OrderThresholdDiscountPromotionDto)promotionDto_2;

    }


}

class OrderThresholdDiscountPromotionDto extends PromotionDto {
  private Double thresholdTotal;
  private Double discountPrice;
  private String messageFired;
  private String messageCouldHaveFired;

}
```

Comment: Request have OrderThresholdDiscountPromotionDto fields. I try to get these fields from PromotionDto referenced instance. I know about casting.

Comment: Your JSON will get translated to `PromotionDto`. Your Request Body has the instance of `PromotionDto`, not `OrderThresholdDiscountPromotionDto ` that's the reason you are getting that type casting error.